# How to get the Style side panel of the HTML panel in Firebug back?

Tags: firebug

The Style side panel that is usually to the right of the HTML panel in Firebug is not displaying. There is, I guess, an obvious solution but I can't find it. How can I get them back?

Comment: if my answer doesn't work just say so & I'll see if I can re-create the same issue and solve it with you ^^ @Roys

Answer (score 0):

In the top right of firebug there's an arrow, click on the arrow and it will come back ^^

Comment: Thanks, I worked it out, clicking on firebug icon > options > reset firebug options and it's fixed

Comment: @RoyS You should have posted you comment as an answer as it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The visibility of the side panels can be toggled since [Firebug 1.12](http://blog.getfirebug.com/2013/07/05/firebug-1-12-beta-2/) via a button at the right of the panel toolbar:

[image: Side Panels Toggle Button]

This works for all panels that have side panels like the *Console*, *HTML*, *CSS* and *Script* panel and their visibility is persistently saved per panel.

You can also reset all Firebug options to get back the default visiblity of the panels via the Firebug menu > *Options* > *Reset All Firebug Options*. Though note that this also resets all other Firebug related options to their defaults.